# How to set a background slideshow behind the text content in materialize?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I want to set a background slideshow behind the text content in materialize. Text content must display on all slides and it shouldn't like carousel. How can I do that? Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to set a background slides show behind the text content. Put below HTML and CSS codes into your .html and .css files respectively.
HTML part:

```
<div class="slider fullscreen">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <img style="max-width: 100%" src="images/paper-boats1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img style="max-width: 100%" src="images/paper-boats2.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img style="max-width: 100%" src="images/paper-boats3.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="text-on-slider">
    //your text content goes here...        
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
#text-on-slider{
   position: absolute;
   height: calc(95vh); 
   margin-top: 0px; 
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: column; 
   justify-content: center; 
   align-items: left; 
   z-index: 2; 
   top: 0; 
   pointer-events: none; 
   width: 100%;
}
```

This worked on me properly. So I hope this also work on you.